# How to specify task in gradle 2.12 with android

Tags: android, task, build.gradle, gradle-experimental

I'm using gradle 2.12 with build tools 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.6.0-alpha5'.
I want to specify some task and I have trouble understanding the syntax. 
I'm getting errors in the task syntax part.  Can someone post an example with task. Thanks!

This is what I have:

```
task ndkBuildName(type:Exec) {
    commandLine '/Users/Anu/android-ndk-r11b/ndk-Build',
            '-C',
            'V=1',
            'NDK_PROJECT_PATH=build/intermediates/ndk',
            'NDK_LIBS_OUT=src/main/jniLibs',
            'APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=src/main/jni/Android.mk',
            'NDK_APPLICATION_MK=src/main/jni/Application.mk'
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
//compile(type: JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn(ndkBuildName)
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: A model of type 'org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.javaCompile' cannot be constructed.  I think I have to use compileJava, just don't know how to use it. If someone could  please post an example it will be helpful.

Comment: **JavaCompile** is not even listed in the Gradle pane (on the right side of Android Studio).  You should look at that pane to see which tasks are available.